# 'OR' statment on 'GROUP BY' postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a query checking dates and counting depending on what month it was made, I need to count two rows and assign it to the correspondent month.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
  to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.complete_date_sent::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as date_ret_sent, 
  count(ret_used.complete_date_sent),   
  count(ret_used.date_second_sms) AS second_count 
FROM ret_used
WHERE ret_used.group_id = 1 
  AND (ret_used.complete_date_sent between '01/01/2019' AND '12/31/2019' OR ret_used.date_second_sms between '01/01/2019' AND '12/31/2019') 
  AND (ret_used.msg_sent = TRUE OR ret_used.second_msg_sent = TRUE)
GROUP BY to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.complete_date_sent::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY date_retention_sent asc
```

Gives me a result:

```
date_ret_sent   |  count |  second_count
-------------------------------------------
09/01/2019      |    3   |     1
10/01/2019      |    1   |     0
NULL            |    0   |     1
```

This is happening because I'm only grouping by the date on the "complete_date_sent" and the 'NULL' value is from "date_second_sms" but it should be on the '10/01/2019' line on the second_count.

Meaning:

```
date_ret_sent   |  count |  second_count
-------------------------------------------
09/01/2019      |    3   |     1
10/01/2019      |    1   |     1
```

Is there a way to put a "OR" or something under the 'GROUP BY' to assign the value to the correspondent date OR am I missing something else.

Comment: Are there null values in the column complete_date_sent?

Comment: Yes, the format of "complete_date_sent" and "date_second_sms" is the same

Comment: So you basically want to `GROUP BY coalesce(possibly_null_value, fallback_value)`?

Comment: I don't think this helps me much, the date for the "date_second_sms" is not NULL. The value is the same as "complete_date_sent". I just need it to know that it should group it in the same date as "complete_date_sent" if they match. So because both are "10/01/2019" it should group them together.

Comment: How can you tell that the NULL row should be grouped with `10/01/2019` and not with `09/01/2019`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `coalesce()` to group by the non null of the 2 dates:

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(
    to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.complete_date_sent::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.date_second_sms::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  ) as date_ret_sent, 
  count(ret_used.complete_date_sent),   
  count(ret_used.date_second_sms) AS second_count 
FROM ret_used
WHERE ret_used.group_id = 1 
  AND (ret_used.complete_date_sent between '01/01/2019' AND '12/31/2019' OR ret_used.date_second_sms between '01/01/2019' AND '12/31/2019') 
  AND (ret_used.msg_sent = TRUE OR ret_used.second_msg_sent = TRUE)
GROUP BY 
  coalesce(
    to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.complete_date_sent::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', (ret_used.date_second_sms::date)), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  )
ORDER BY date_retention_sent asc
```

Comment: I don't think this helps me much, the date for the "date_second_sms" is not NULL. The value is the same as "complete_date_sent". I just need it to know that it should group it in the same date as "complete_date_sent" if they match. So because both are "10/01/2019" it should group them together.

Comment: If they were both 10/01/2019 then you would not get NULL in the results.